# InfluxDB gives me an empty list (or generator) on queries with dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, influxdb, influxdb-python

I'm trying to do a simple query on InfluxDB from date to date, like this:

```
'SELECT * FROM "x" WHERE time > '2016-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z' AND time < '2016-02-01T00:00:00.000000000Z'
```

In theory, this should work. In practice, it gives me an empty list (or a generator that returns nothing, depends how I query it), where if I just use now() - Xd it works (but it's too unprecise for what I need to do). I've tried using single quotes, double quotes, I've tried removing T and Z, tried without nanoseconds, just with the date, without finishing date... No matter what, it either gives me an empty list, or a Syntax error. 
If I use double quotes on the entire query it gives me a Syntax Error too. If I use single quotes on the db name, Syntax Error. I also tried epoch, no luck.

What could be the problem? I'm running out of ideas, been banging my head on this for 4 full days.
PS I'm using python 3.7, InfluxDB 1.7.9, InfluxDB Python Client 5.2.3, on MacOs 10.12.6.

Comment: Does data exist for that period? Do you have a retention policy set up on that db?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! The answer was: "SELECT * FROM \"x\" WHERE time > '2016-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z' AND time < '2016-02-01T00:00:00.000000000Z'"